# Get complex angle when computing quaternions (Satellite attitude)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, quaternions

I am modelling a, so far uncontrolled, satellite in MATLAB , along with its attitude. I have been researching about this matter and found that quaternions are the way to go , since they don't have singularities. My goal was to get angular velocities in each axis (body frame) from the satellite motion equations :

$$I \frac{\partial ^2\theta}{\partial t^2} + \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t} \times I \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t} = \sum \tau$$

From which I got the angular velocity in each axis for every step of my simulation.

I then computed the attitude quaternions using a formula I saw here :

$$ q_{new} = q_{old} + \frac{dt}{2} \cdot \omega \cdot q_{old} ,$$ in which $ \omega\ $ is the angular velocity.

It seemed to work well but when I computed the Euler angles, using this : 
\begin{align}
\phi &= atan2 (2(q_0q_1 + q_2q_3), 1- 2(q_1^2+q_2^2)) \\
\theta &= asin (2(q_0q_2-q_3q_1)) \\
\psi &= atan2 (2(q_0q_3+q_1q_2), 1-2 (q_2^2+q_3q_1))
\end{align}

I got complex results in the pitch axis (outside the domain of the $asin$ function), which means something is obviously wrong but I can't think of any solution besides trying randomly until something makes sense. I even tried to divide the angular velocity by its norm but it didn't help.

Does anyone know which of my steps is wrong? I hope I was clear enough.

Thanks in advance,
Hugo

Comment: I think we'll need more details, which means you'll need to learn to typeset your formulas so people can read them: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I didn't know how to type equations here, will do it asap.

Comment: I found the "formula I saw here" , well here : https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/108920/applying-angular-velocity-to-quaternion

Comment: You need to normalize the quaternion before the angle computations, or at least compensate for it in the $\arcsin$ computation. Also think about some higher order methods, Euler or second order will quickly accumulate errors.

Comment: Are you sure about the order of the factors in the product? Remember that quaternions are non-communative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm somewhat leery of taking the statements in the source of the equation at face value. I don't think they're explained very well.

Extracting a factor of $q_\text{old}$ on the right-hand side of the equation you used, we get

$$ q_\text{new} = q_\text{old} + \frac t2 \mathbf\omega \,q_\text{old}
= \left(1 + \frac t2 \mathbf\omega\right) q_\text{old}. $$

The composition of rotations in quaternions (what you're trying to do here) is accomplished by multiplication of one unit quaternion (in this case $q_\text{old}$)
by another unit quaternion.
In the equation above we multiply $q_\text{old}$ by $1 + \frac t2 \mathbf\omega,$
which is a quaternion but not a *unit* quaternion (unless $t=0$ or $\mathbf\omega=0$).

I think the exact formula for a constant rotation $\mathbf\omega$ for time $t$ is actually

$$ q_\text{new} = \exp\left(\frac t2 \mathbf\omega\right) q_\text{old}, $$

using the exponential function $\exp(\cdot).$
The expression $1 + \frac t2 \mathbf\omega$ is a truncated Taylor series of 
$\exp\left(\frac t2 \mathbf\omega\right),$ that is, a first-order approximation.
If $\frac t2 \mathbf\omega$ is very small then it's a reasonably good approximation,
so if you take very small steps and renormalize the result (scale it down to make it a unit quaternion again) after every step, you'll get better results.

---

An alternative approximation of the exponential function
(adapted from the comments) is

$$
\frac{1 + (t/4) \mathbf\omega}{1 − (t/4) \mathbf\omega}
=\frac{(1 + (t/4) \mathbf\omega)^2}
      {1+\lvert \mathbf\omega \rvert^2\,t^2/16}.
$$

This is mathematically a unit quaternion, so you should not have to "normalize" the result. Be aware, however, that due to the inherent inaccuracies of floating-point arithmetic, when you do this on a computer you may get a result for a computation such as $2(q_0q_2 - q_3q_1)$ that is ever so slightly greater than $1$ or less than $-1.$ You can set $\theta$ to $\pm\frac\pi2$ in those cases. (On the other hand if you get something like $1.01$ then there is probably still some error in the formulas or their implementation.)

Comment: As a simple first correction, one could take the most simple Padé approximant $q_{new}=(1+ω\,dt/4)(1-ω\,dt/4)^{-1}q_{old}$, as that gives a norm 1 factor.

Comment: @LutzLehmann That's a useful fact I was not aware of. May I append that to my answer, or would you like to post it in an answer of your own?

Comment: I tried David's solution and if I didn't make any mistakes implementing it, I think I can't compute a step small enough that it would work. But it makes sense so I guess its helpful in other contexts!

Comment: Lutz Lehmann, how am I to invert a non-square matrix? Sorry for my ignorance!

Comment: Since my "solution" was "do what you're doing now, but with a small value of $t$ and scale the result back down to a unit quaternion after every step," by definition at the end you will have a unit quaternion and you should be able to convert it back to Euler angles using standard formulas. I haven't checked your particular formulas for that, though.

Comment: Sure, I meant using the exp function rather than the simplified original formula. My problem was that I wasn't normalizing it after each step which of course your answer solved! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @HugoPontes You apply quaternion arithmetic, which is similar to complex arithmetic. It gives $$(1+ω\,dt/4)(1−ω\,dt/4)^{−1}=(1+ω\,dt/4)^2/(1+\|ω\|^2\,dt^2/16).$$ @ David K: Yes, please use it, it is too small an addition to make an extra answer out of it.

Comment: @LutzLehmann it worked, thanks! I'm implementing it

Comment: I've been looking more into it and I get the same results for all methods, which are quaternions that oscillate way too much. Their plot is like this for most quaternions : https://imgur.com/Y4OJQfy. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @HugoPontes : If that result is to be considered unrealistic depends on the initial condition and external forces. The plot is for about 8 hours, the density you could get with a couple hundred revolutions, which is not that much for an object the size of a satellite. You would have to write more about the physics and how you translated this into code.

Comment: @LutzLehmann the result is unrealistic because it doens't make sense when you look at the spin rates . This would mean the satellite would spin in a different direction in every step. This was happening because I was unfamiliar with quaternion arithmetic and tried to use an actual one instead of an identity matrix. I still haven't managed to make David's equation work but I expect I will soon!

Comment: A rotating body in free-fall with a non-spherical moment of inertia tends to tumble. What is the initial magnitude of the satellite's rotation around each axis in radians per second? One axis is clearly wobbling about $30$ degrees in each direction from a reference plane; the plot would be more informative if you changed the scale on the horizontal axis so you were only showing us two or three oscillations, then we could see if the rate is unrealistic compared to your rotation rates.

Comment: @DavidK the satellite has 0 spin rate in every axis,but is acted on by perturbance torques, I really don't think it makes sense but tell me what you think :                  This is the zoomed in plot : https://imgur.com/5Aqb4Vp                                        The corresponding spin rates : https://imgur.com/rO0a2es                                    The implementation that I think is correct produced these results :          Quaternions x time : https://imgur.com/f6lZxpf                                                      Spin rate : https://imgur.com/awb83ZQ

Comment: It looks like you have one implementation that works and one that doesn't. I'm not sure what we do next. Do you want to debug the non-working implementation and figure out what went wrong? It might be a units conversion error or a missing set of parentheses in some expression. Graphs probably won't pinpoint exactly where the error is, though they might help you identify when some intermediate result of one of the calculations is much too large or small.

Comment: Well I think the implementation that works is sufficient, I was hoping that the kind of results I obtained earlier (the high frequency quaternions) was some "classic mistake" or something of the sort! But I have a bit of a deadline for this part of my work and I already sent the results to my tutor and I think it's beneficial that I move on to other issues! But thanks so much for all the help you have been incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You may have to normalize your quaternion, dividing it by its absolute value at each stage so you always have $q_0^2+q_1^2+q_2^2+q_3^2=1$ after this division.

Then the argument of the arcsin function should stay in range.  The constrained extremal values of

$f=2(q_0q_2-q_1q_3)$

under the normalization constraint $q_0^2+q_1^2+q_2^2+q_3^2=1$ is found via Lagrange multipliers to occur when all $q_2=\pm q_0, q_3=\pm q_1$, and this forces the extrema of $f=\pm1$.

Comment: This simple solution worked to thebest of my knowledge. I no longer get complex angles. I will try the other solution by LutzLehmann to see which is best

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reference to how the 3D game engine people do rotations using quaternions: https://www.3dgep.com/understanding-quaternions/

In particular, for this problem, I suggest working through SLERPing. I suspect you might find there is a better modelling solution by staying within quaternion arithmetic.

Enjoy! (It's not my stuff, I just found it useful.)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! But I don't think it helps my question in particular since I only have the initial quaternion and want to know how the rotation (following quaternions) evolves with angular velocity inputs in each step.

Comment: Interpolation using quaternions is between two specified qs. Easy enough to extrapolate, though.

Comment: Please provide details about the perturbance torques. In particular, how do they relate to orientation of the satellite?

Comment: I can't interpolate since I only have the initial quaternion, unless I'm missing something. The torques come mostly from 4 sources : gravity gradient , solar flux, aerodynamic drag and from the interaction of the satellite's metallic parts with the magnetic field. They interact with the orientation of the satellite through the differential equation in the original question